# Using rowspan and colspan in a customized table

Tags: html, html-table

[image: Image of what I need]

I'm very new at HTML table features, but i understand HTML.

I have to create a table exactly like the image, but I already have lost a good time trying to do it.

I think the best way to do it is work with 'rowspan',
but I don't know how exactly.

Could someone give me a little help, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the HTML you have already tried?

Comment: I'm frankly not sure what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to simply have some empty cells?

Answer (score 0):

Use it as an attribute.
This example is for the first row (next to 110)

`<td colspan="6"></td>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're having difficulty with, but if you're struggling with table-cell styling, you can either utilize CSS' `nth-child()` selector or use classes to pinpoint specific cells for styling application.

I've recreated your table in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/3Lnabx9n/).